# Simple Inverse Matrix Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, matrix-equations

I believe this inequality is true, but I am not sure how to show it rigorously.

For Matrices $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ where $A^{-1}, B^{-1} \preceq I$ where I is a matrix of all 1's and this inequality (I believe) represents that each element is less than 1, I want to show the following
$$
||A^{-1} - B^{-1}|| = ||A^{-1}A^{-1}A - B^{-1}B^{-1}B|| \le ||A-B||
$$
My reasoning behind me doing this is that I know, $|1/5-1/3| \le |5-3|$ and we can replace 5 or 3 with any natural numbers and this will work.

So how can I rigorously show this for my matrix inequality above? Or is it actually fine as is, as long as I state $A^{-1}, B^{-1} \preceq I$ ?

Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: What do you mean by "this inequality (I believe) represents that each element is less than $1$"? Is this a definition or your belief about what you think this notation already means? The standard meaning of $A \le B$ for matrices is that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices and $B - A$ is positive-semidefinite. Also, since the notation here is possibly nonstandard, what do you mean by $\| A \|$? The operator norm?

Comment: I am 99% certain this inequality means what I stated, I wrote I believe because the latex name for this inequality made no sense to me. and by ||.|| I mean any norm.

Comment: You have the identity matrix there on the RHS; according to you, what does $A \preceq B$ mean if $A$ and $B$ are two matrices? If it means $a_{ij} \le b_{ij}$ this isn't consistent with your use of the identity matrix and you want the all-ones matrix.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Completely right. I edited my post, thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure if this holds for any norm, only submultiplicative norms. Also perhaps you mean that the modulus of the entries are bounded by one?

Answer (score 1):

Use identity $A^{-1}-B^{-1}=A^{-1}(B-A)B^{-1}$ and the fact that $\|A^{-1}\|\leq 1$ and $\|B^{-1}\|<1$.

Comment: Neat. Except that your claimed inequalities would not hold for the hypothesis of the newest version of the post (where inequalities are to be intended entrywise)